# There is not much option of "find_element" options in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium learning by watching some youtube videos.

In the videos, there are many options when finding elements such as "find_element_by_class_ name, find_element_by_id" so on but mine show only a few options.. can anyone tell me why?
[image]

Comment: Because those videos are old and use deprecated methods

Answer (score 1):

With the availability of [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) a couple of things have changed and you can't locate elements with `find_elements_by_*` commands now. You should do something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('path_to_chrome_driver'), options)

driver.get('your_url.com')

driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '''copied xpath from the browser''')

... #other code here

driver.close()
```

Simply change your `find_element_by_*` to `find_element(By.*,...)`
if * was all lower case it's now all uppercase too. for more info check the [selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Comment: I think that `by` might be deprecated too. Just `find_elements("xpath", expression)` should be preferred

Comment: By is not deprecated till now. I'm using it for my projects and it's not throwing any deprecation messages.

Comment: Here's [the code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/common/by.py) for that. It seems pretty useless and I honestly don't understand the point.